# Including JSON in Node.js res.redirect()

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

**What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the JSON contents of the `message` variable can be sent from the Node.js server to the AngularJS client?**

The following code is in the routing file of a Node.js app.  The code below generates JSON and then redirects control to the `redirectURL='/'` handler, which sends the `./public/index.html` file to the AngularJS client.

It is important that the JSON `message` be sent to the AngularJS client in this transaction, so that the AngularJS browser app can be responsible for preserving the user's unique identity.  That way, subsequent requests from AngularJS browser apps can be served by any of hundreds of clones of this Node.js app, and each clone will use the JSON that it receives with each request to connect with a Redis cluster to manage user identity across multiple requests.  This will enable Node.js to not have to remember user identities.

```
app.get('/some_endpoint', function(req, res) {
    var redirectURL = '/';
    request.post(otherServerUrl, function(err, response, body){
        if(err){console.log('ERROR with token request.')}
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        getUser(data.access_token).then(function(message) {
            console.log('in callback, jwtJSON is: ');console.log(message);
            res.redirect(redirectURL);
        });
    });
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/index.html'); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
});
```

**Note that the `app.get('*', function(req, res)` needs to be able to also serve requests from users that have not been redirected from `app.get('/some_endpoint', function(req, res)` and who thus do not have any `message` JSON at the server to be sent to the browser app.**

Comment: If I understand your question right, are you saying your frontend isn't receiving the contents of message variable?

Comment: Change `res.redirect(redirectURL)` to `res.json(message)`?

Comment: @AnveshChecka  Yes, you understand correctly.  The Angular app just receives index.html.

Comment: @jfriend00 The redirect in the code above is part of a sequence processing a return from a different server (OAuth authentication), so the user does not have a page from the present site in their browser to receive the JSON.  I want to send them the page and the JSON together at the point where the user is being returned to the web site by the OAuth flow..

Comment: Then, the question doesn't really make sense to me.  If there's no receiving Javascript to do anything with JSON and all you can do here in the flow is redirect, then what are expecting to send JSON to?  You either have something at the other end of this request that can process JSON or you don't.  Which is it?

Comment: @jfriend00 I will be writing AngulaJS to handle the JWT at the web browser.  When the AngularJS app makes requests to the Node.js instances, the given Node.js instance will decompose the JWT and check the Redis server/cluster to see if the user exists, etc.  So the Node.js is just a pass through agent between the AngularJS app, the Redis identity management, and other servers who will receive the credentials which the Redis server/cluster will pass through the Node.js instance.

Comment: None of that explained why you're trying to do both a redirect and return JSON in the same step.  Pick one or the other.

Comment: @jfriend00 Because this is the endpoint which receives the callback from the `OAuth` authorization server.  The user has just been at the authorization server's site, and has been redirected to this node.js instance, which now has to redirect the user to the AngularJS app served up by this Node.js instance.  However, the username, etc from the `OAuth` authentication need to be put into a JWT and sent to the AngularJS app in the same transaction in order for the Node.js instance to be completely free of any need to persist user data.  Does this make sense now?

Comment: Then, put your information into query parameters in the redirect URL.  That's a common way to send info to a redirected page.  The redirected page can then parse the query parameters from its own URL to get the information.  Either that or a cookie, but cookies can be tricky if you're switching domains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to pass information to a page that will be loaded from a redirection, then the usual way to do that is to encode the information as query parameters on the redirect URL.

This will get passed through the redirect to the newly loaded page and that page can then parse the query parameters to grab the information.

It is also possible to put information into a cookie before the redirect and have the redirected page get info from the cookie, but if you are using different domains during the redirect process, the cookie can be complicated or impractical (since cookies are associated with a specific domain).

You can't just return JSON with the redirect response because a redirect will not pass the JSON on to the redirected page - that's not how redirects work.  A redirect just loads the page that corresponds to the new URL.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to talk me through this.

Comment: @FirstOfMany - FYI, for the future.  What would have clarified things a lot quicker was a flow diagram showing what information was trying to get from what request to what page.  It wasn't until an hour ago that I finally understood what you were trying to do.  Anyway, glad you got it sorted now.